# How to get saved images in Elgg

Tags: php, html, elgg

I'm saving an **entity** **object** of type **entity** and **subtype** **album**. When saving the album, I also save it with image files who's `$ownerGUID = $album-> GUID`. They get uploaded OK. The problem I'm now having is when it comes to retrieving the images.

How can I go about listing all the images that belong to a particular album?

Thank you all in advance.

**Elgg 2.X**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$content = elgg_list_entities(array(type=>'object',subtype=>'image'
                                    'owner_guid'=>$album->guid  
                          ));
```